# How to store Data when page refresh in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular4-router, userid

I am new in Angular2/4. In my interface Details fetching and saving are working properly. But when we refresh the interface the fetched details are gone. How can we solve this issue with out loosing the interface details after refresh

**This is my Login.component.ts file**

```
   btnlogin() {
    this.message = '';
    this.storage.clear();

    if (this.validate() == true) {
        this._enqService.FetchUserDetails(this.username, this.password).subscribe(userData => {
            if (userData.length == 0)
                this.message = " * Username/Password not correct";

            else {
                userData.forEach(item => {
                    this._loginService._userid = item.UserID;
                    this._loginService._username = item.UserName;
                    //if (this._loginService.selectedshopid == undefined || this._loginService.selectedshopid == 0) {
                    //    this.messages = '* Please Select a Shop';
                    //    return false;
                    //}
                    this._router.navigate(['/enquirydetails']);
                });
            }

        },
            error => {
                console.error(error);
                this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
            });
    }
}
 validate(): boolean {
    if (this.username == '' || this.password == '' || this.username == undefined || this.password == undefined) {
        this.message = '* Please enter username/password';
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

**This is my logoutcomponent.ts**

```
       constructor(private router: Router, location: Location, private storage: 
     LocalStorageService)
    {
        this.location = location;
        router.events.subscribe((val) => {
            if (this.location.path() != '') {
                this.route = location.path();
            }
        });

    } 
    setUserName()
    {
        //alert('calling setusername');
        this.UserName = this.storage.retrieve('usernamevalue');
    }

    logout() {

        this.router.navigate(['Login']);
        this.storage.clear('boundvalue');
        this.storage.clear('uservalue');
        this.storage.clear();
        //alert(this.storage.retrieve('boundvalue'));
        //alert(this.storage.retrieve('uservalue'));
    } 
    //  ngOnInit() {
   //   this.router.navigate([''])
   //  }
}
```

Comment: (i want like this , The logged in user details are stored in local storage so the user will stay logged in if they refresh the browser and also between browser sessions until they logout)

Comment: https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `LocalStorageService` is your own library hence I have not considered that in the answer.

After the user has successfully logged in store the userId and userName in local storage like this:

```
userData.forEach(item => {
    this._loginService._userid = item.UserID;
    this._loginService._username = item.UserName;

    //save to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem(userId, item.UserID);
    localStorage.setItem(userName, item.UserName);

    this._router.navigate(['/enquirydetails']);
});
```

In your logout method you delete the user values from localStorage.

```
logout() {

    this.router.navigate(['Login']);
    this.storage.clear('boundvalue');
    this.storage.clear('uservalue');
    this.storage.clear();
    // delete from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem(userId);
    localStorage.removeItem(userName);
}
```

To check the user is logged in, I would suggest using a Route Guard. Within this you can get the values from localStorage and validate if the user is logged in.

```
localStorage.getItem(userId);
localStorage.getItem(userName);
```

You can learn about the Route Guard here: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

**Note:** The above is just an example, since I'm unaware of your complete application. A proper user authentication using sessionId/userHash should be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of "sessionstorage" or "localStorage" for storing data and fetch them later for your use.

> sessionStorage, localStorage and Cookies all are used to store data on the client side. Each one has its own storage and expiration limit. sessionStorage: similar to localStorage but expires when the browser closed (not the tab). Cookie: stores data that has to be sent back to the server with subsequent requests.

I think SessionStorage is suitable for your need. it gets cleared once you close the session/ close browser. You can create a hashMap and store the required Info there and check for it when page loads, if not available try to use the info sent by server.